# how to pass a + sign in camel exec uri

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I'm using Camel with spring xml. When I try to call find through camel's exec-component there is certain problems to get the arguments right.

I want to call 'find /somepath/ -mtime +10'

My camel route have this to element.

```
<to uri="exec:find?args=/somepath/ -mtime +30 -delete" />
```

and in the log I get

```
2017-11-06 20:12:00,172 INFO  [org.apache.camel.component.exec.ExecProducer] (DefaultQuartzScheduler-noderoutes_Worker-10) The command ExecCommand [args=[/tmp/integrator/msglog/, -mtime,  **30**, -print], executable=find, timeout=9223372036854775807, outFile=null, workingDir=null, useStderrOnEmptyStdout=true] had exit value 0
```

Where we can see that the +sign is dropped and find command will fail due to the missing +.
I tried different ways to escape or encode the + without success. Anyone how knows a way protect the +sign ?

Comment: Which ways did you try to encode the ``+`` character? ``&#43;`` should work in theory.

Comment: I tried to encode with %2B and &#002B, both disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [RAW()](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html)

```
<to uri="exec:find?args=RAW(/somepath/ -mtime +30 -delete)" />
```

Comment: Wrapping the complete args in RAW just got me some extra '+', since RAW seem to replace space with + in some kind of escaping.
I got this in the log after wrapping all args in RAW.

    2017-11-07 13:02:00,350 ERROR [org.apache.camel.component.exec.ExecProducer] (DefaultQuartzScheduler-noderoutes_Worker-6) The command ExecCommand [args=[RAW(/tmp/integrator/msglog/+-mtime++10+-print], executable=find, timeout=9223372036854775807, outFile=null, workingDir=null, useStderrOnEmptyStdout=false] returned exit value 1

Answer (score 0):

After I have tried both escaping the + and wrapping all args or just parts of the args in RAW I introduced another layer. I put the call to find in a script and just have the path and number of days as argument to exec.

```
<to uri="exec:/somepath/script.sh?args=/startpath/ 30" />
```

I guess there is just to many layers of coding/decoding going on before the command line is put to the os.